# Fresh I-539 Reapplication after denial of Change of Status

Tags: usa, visa, student-visa

I entered the US on 24th February 2020, my visa expires 2nd April 2020. I applied for Change of status from B2 to F1 Student Status on 8th June 2020 even though my I-94 expires on 23rd August. I was eventually denied change of status because I omitted an application for Extension of Status same time. I was given 33 days to depart.

Can I reapply this time for change of status and extension of stay within the 33 days granted to me?

Comment: On what date was your change of status application denied?

Answer (score 1):

No, you generally cannot apply for Change of Status if you are already out of status. In rare cases where USCIS might give an exception for good cause to file late, but your case does not seem like a case that would qualify.